# Image of $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ under transformation $(x,y) \rightarrow (u,v)$

Tags: geometry, transformation

What is the image of the set $$A=\{ (x,y) : 0\le x \le a\ , \ 1\le y\}$$

under the transformation $(x,y) \rightarrow (u,v)$ where $$u=x/y$$
$$v=x$$

The parameter $a$ is positive.
I got a 'triangle' in the $(u,v)$ plane, that is the bit below the diagonal of the square with side $a$ with its lower left corner at the origin. But I'm having trouble quickly seeing this, is there a nice method for doing such exercises?

Comment: I get the triangle **above** the diagonal of that same square, i.e. with vertices $\,(0,0)\;,\;(a,a)\;,\;\;(0,a)\;$ , *but* it doesn't contain the vertex $\,(0,a)\,$...check this as it seems to be *at least* one of us two is wrong.

Comment: For $a=1$, the point $x=0.25$, $y=100$ gets transformed into $u=0.0025$, $v=0.25$ so you're right. I found my mistake, somewhere along the way i turned a $v/u$ into $u/v$. As for the missing vertex, I wasn't paying too much attention to single points since I only needed the area to integrate over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a triangle in the $u$-$v$ plane that is **above** the diagonal of the square you describe, which has vertices at the origin, at $(a, a)$ and at $0, a$. It does not however, contain $(0, a)$: we get that for $a = 1$, $$(x, y) = (0.25, 100) \mapsto (u, v) = (0.0025, 0.25)$$

Comment: for my dear friend ${}{}{+}$